# Can't get original_transaction_id from status update notification keys of apple

Tags: in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription, auto-renewable

I'm implementing on ***Status Update Notifications*** from Apple's In app purchase programming guide.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html

I have done to setup a subscription status URL and I have received a response from apple server, but I can't get ***original_transaction_id*** keys in table 6-3 on documentation. With this keys, Can I get transaction receipts for an individual customer’s subscription?.

I realised that I got  `original_transaction_id` field in `latest_receipt_info`. Is that same value with `original_transaction_id` outside keys ( the same level object key with latest_receipt_info ) ?.

***[Update]***

This post said that we will use `original_transaction_id` to detect customer receipt. The problem is I can't get `original_transaction_id` field on apple server response. What's wrong with me?

[How do you determine the customer/user when receiving an Apple statusUpdateNotification for auto renewing subscriptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45364325/how-do-you-determine-the-customer-user-when-receiving-an-apple-statusupdatenotif)

My response have

```
{ 
latest_receipt: base 64 code,
latest_receipt_info:
    { original_purchase_date_pst: '2017-07-30 21:06:59 America/Los_Angeles',
      purchase_date_ms: '1502436055000',
      unique_identifier: 'aa68f27daea1c90b8xxxxxxxxxxx02485e0b80de3',
      original_transaction_id: '10000xxxx972063',
      expires_date: '1502436355000',
      transaction_id: '10000xxx23641817',
      original_purchase_date_ms: '1501474019000',
      web_order_line_item_id: '10000000xxxxxx38',
      bvrs: '627',
      unique_vendor_identifier: '5E5C6E0F-xxxxxxxxxxxx-DFE8D5F8E568',
      expires_date_formatted_pst: '2017-08-11 00:25:55 America/Los_Angeles',
      item_id: '1177296522',
      expires_date_formatted: '2017-08-11 07:25:55 Etc/GMT',
      product_id: 'fisadhasdjasjdjjj',
      purchase_date: '2017-08-11 07:20:55 Etc/GMT',
      original_purchase_date: '2017-07-31 04:06:59 Etc/GMT',
      bid: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      purchase_date_pst: '2017-08-11 00:20:55 America/Los_Angeles',
      quantity: '1' },
environment: 'Sandbox',
auto_renew_status: 'true',
password: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
auto_renew_product_id: 'fisadhasdjasjdjjj',
notification_type: 'RENEWAL' }
```

missing `original_transaction_id` keys

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am facing the same thing. It appears that the documentation is incorrect. All of my sandbox server notifications have not included original_transaction_id as a top level property, it is only in the latest_receipt_info and latest_expired_receipt_info.

Comment: I use `original_transaction_id` in `latest_receipt_info` to renewable. Can't get original_transaction_id as a top level property @jmichas

Comment: It seems like a bug either in their notification or an error in the documentation. I'm facing the same issue but I never trust notifications and always validate `latest_receipt` on iTunes and read data from there.

Comment: Seems to be fixed since 23/03/2022, we are getting the field on top level again since then, before it was not set.